# Determine the currents in the following circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Here I have such a problem. I'm asked to determine the values of currents in this circuit(the circuit is in permanent sinusoidal regim). The double-sided arrow in the image represents the magnetic coupling:

[image]

Where: E = 140 V, L1 = 4mH, L2 = 20mH,
       R1 = 1 Ohm, L3 = 6 mH, C2 = \$ 500 * 10^{-6} F\$
       ,\$Z_s = 1 - 2j\$, \$ w = 1000 \frac{rad}{s} \$.

\$ 1mH = 1 * 10^{-3} H \$

C1,C2, C3 = capacitors

\$R_k  \$ = resistors

\$L_k  \$ = inductors

E = voltage source

The problem is I do not know how to deal with impedance \$ Z_s\$ while  composing the system using ***Theorem Joubert and Kirchhoff*** in complex.

I hope I was understandable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: E is a sin source? Because at first look it looks like E is a DC source because of you formulate your question

Comment: No, it isn't. I want to use it as it is 140 V, using Th. Joubert and Kirchhoff

Comment: The symbol off E is a current source.

Comment: No, here it's a voltage source

Comment: 140 V what? What is the waveform in time space?

Comment: I never heard of "Theorem Joubert and Kirchhoff". I know the Laplace Transform for Transient circuit and the Fourrier Transform for Permanent Sin regime

Comment: @MathieuL I think that's a problem, because I know only this (Joubert and Kirchhoff). But it's not a transient circuit.

Comment: To solve the circuit for a constant AC input (assuming that is what E actually is) you need to convert everything to complex impedances and solve using Kirchoff's current law. Zs is just already done for you.

Comment: Well, the complex impedance depend of what waveform is applied.

Comment: @Jon But Is Zs  the impedance for the edge that contains R2, C2, and R3 ? Generally, how do I write the formula: \$U = i_s(R_2  + Z_s + j(wL_3 - 1/{wC_3})) + jwL_{23}i_1\$ ? Jon, can you, please, present only the formula for the right "eye" of the circuit, using Kirchoff and Joubert ?

Comment: @Jon Sorry for being annoying, but can you, please, post the Kirchhoff's for the right "eye" of the circuit ?

Comment: Could you include a statement of the "Theorem Joubert and Kirchoff" that you are referring to? When I google "Joubert theorem" I get a bunch stuff that looks like number theory. When I google "Joubert Kirchoff theorem" this question is the top and only relevant hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the equation from what the English-speaking world calls Kirchoff's Voltage Law (KVL), for the right-side mesh of your circuit, it's

$$-V_{C3} + V_{R2} + V_{C2} + V_{Zn} + V_{L3} = 0$$

You will now have to guess (or work out) what direction convention I chose for each element, since you didn't include any polarity markers in your schematic.

Then you will have to substitute in the characteristic behavior of each element for the voltage variables, to get an equation that just depends on the mesh currents.

From there (and the similar equation for the left side mesh) you will be able to solve for the currents.

Comment: But Vzn = Zn * in (where \$i_n\$ is the current), yes ?

Comment: Yes, except for L3, you have to include the magnetic coupling part.

Comment: So is it right: \$-i_{C3} * (-j/wC_3) + i_{C2}*(R_2 + j(wL_3 - j/wC_2)) + jwL_{23} * i_{R1} + Z_n*i_{C2} = 0\$

Comment: I would just name the two mesh currents \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$, but it looks like you have the terms basically right.